# Can we retrieve Dictionary<A,B> elements in the order in which they were inserted?

Tags: c#

How can we retrieve `Dictionary<A,B>` elements in the order in which they were inserted? If dictionary doesn't support this then which object should i use which gives the behavior of dictionary but also allows me to get the elements in the order in which they were inserted.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no guarantee that you can retrieve the elements from a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` in order. If this is the behavior that you desire, just encapsulate it into a class:

```
class DictionaryWithKeysOrderedByInsertion<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> {
    private readonly List<TKey> keys = new List<TKey>();
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator() {
        foreach(var key in keys) { 
            yield return new KeyValuePair(key, dictionary[key]));
        }
    }

    // etc.
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary is unordered, if you want them back in the order they were inserted, you might want to consider the generic [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

No, dictionary does not have such functionality.

You can

1. use 2 structures and insert into both at the same time - List/LinkedList to store sequence and dictionary to provide fast lookup.
2. you can add information about insertion time to entries stored in the dictionary.